# $.getJSON doesn't call the "successful" function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an issue with `.getJSON`.

I have these two calls, but the first `alert` is never shown:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ChartData")',null,
        function (rdata) {

            alert('data');

        });

        $.post('@Url.Action("ChartData")', null,
        function (rdata) {

            var rdataE = eval(rdata);
            alert(rdata.data);

        });

</script>
```

I have this controller action:

```
    public JsonResult ChartData()
    {
        return Json(new { data = "my data" });
    }
```

I have a breakpoint in the last line, and I can see how it is called twice, but for a reason I don't understand, in the first call the `alert` is never shown.

I have added the following code at the beginning:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings, thrownError) {
    alert('error!');
});
```

And I can see that there is an error, but I don't know how to check which.

Any idea?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your controller action return to this:

```
return Json(new { data = "my data" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: :O It works! I thought getJSON was already a POST request... :facepalm: Thanks!